# The minimum of $I_{n,k}=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{3+2\cos(nx)+2\cos(kx)+2\cos(nx+kx)}dx$ is attained for $k=n$

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, definite-integrals

I have the following conjecture: ``For each given $n\in\mathbb{N},\ n\ge 2$ the minimum of the sequence of integrals $I_{n,k}=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{3+2\cos(nx)+2\cos(kx)+2\cos(nx+kx)}dx,\ k=1,2,\dots,n$ is attained for $k=n$''.

I checked this for $n=2$ ($I_{2,1}=10.052307$, $I_{2,2}=9.022598$), $n=3$ ($I_{3,1}=9.900680$, $I_{3,2}=9.924421 $, $I_{3,3}=9.022598$), $n=4$ ($I_{4,1}=9.859090$, $I_{4,2}=10.052307$, $I_{4,3}=9.903215$, $I_{4,4}=9.022598$), ..., until $n=50$.

The final value of $I_{n,n}$ does not depend on $n$, but it is not very clear for me why this value is the minimum value. Could someone give me a hint on how to proceed?

**Edit:**

$\bullet$ The square root is well defined as
\begin{multline*}
3+2\cos(nx)+2\cos(kx)+2\cos(nx+kx)\hfill\\=\Biggl[2\cos\Bigl(\frac{n+k}{2}x\Bigr)\cos\Bigl(\frac{n-k}{2}x\Bigr)+1\Biggr]^2+4\cos^2\Bigl(\frac{n+k}{2}x\Bigr) \sin^2\Bigl(\frac{n-k}{2}x\Bigr)\ge 0
\end{multline*}
for every $k,n,x$.

$\bullet$ Since $2\cos(x)+1<0$ iff $x\in\Bigl(\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{4\pi}{3}\Bigr)$ one can easily deduce that
\begin{align*}
I_{n,n}=I_{1,1}& =\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{3+4\cos(x)+2\cos(2x)}dx=\int_0^{2\pi}|2\cos(x)+1|dx\\
& =\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}}(2\cos(x)+1)dx-\int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\frac{4\pi}{3}}(2\cos(x)+1)dx+\int_{\frac{4\pi}{3}}^{2\pi}(2\cos(x)+1)dx\\
& =4\sqrt{3}+\frac{2\pi}{3}\ \text{for every $n\ge 1$.}
\end{align*}

$\bullet$ Let $f$ and $g$ be periodical functions with period $2\pi$. Then
\begin{equation*}
I_{n,k}(f,g)=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{3+2\cos(nx)+2\cos(kx)+2\cos(nx+kx)}+f(kx)+g(nx)dx
\end{equation*}
attains its minimum for $k=n$ if and only if $I_{n,k}$ attains its minimum for $k=n$.

$\bullet$ $\sqrt{3+2\cos(nx)+2\cos(kx)+2\cos(nx+kx)}=|1+e^{inx}+e^{i(n+k)x}|$ for every $n,k,x$.

Comment: One easily computes $$I_{n,n}=4\sqrt{3}+{2\pi\over3}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you. I knew that such a computation is easy to obtain.

Comment: I am reasonably certain that the square root term can be written as a finite sum of sines, cosines, and constant terms---likely involving sums and differences of $nx$, $kx$, $nx/2$, and $kx/2$. Of course if I knew this for sure I'd have a bounty. :-)

Comment: Here's one thing we know: if $3+2\cos(nx)+2\cos(kx)+2\cos(nx+kx)\geq 0$ for all $x$, then that term can be written as the square of another trigonometric polynomial. But then you're left with the integral of an absolute value of a trigonometric polynomial, so it might not be much progress.

Comment: @Michael Grant It is indeed known that $3+2\cos(nx)+2\cos(kx)+2\cos(nx+kx)\ge 0$ for every $x$. For example, it can be written as $[2\cos(\frac{n+k}{2}x)\cos(\frac{n-k}{2}x)+1]^2+4\cos(\frac{n+k}{2}x)^2 \sin(\frac{n-k}{2}x)^2$.

Comment: Great. Then it can be written as the square of a sum of a finite number of trigonometric terms. (Fejér-Reisz spectral factorization lemma.) Might be worth trying to find that.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how it can help us to solve the problem. If we could erase, somehow, the square root.

Comment: @Michael Grant $|1+e^{inx}+e^{i(n+k)x}|$

Comment: Hmm. That is a wrinkle. I was hoping for a real trig polynomial :-( This may indicate a dead end.

Comment: Maybe a helpful observation would be that the sum $\sqrt{3+2\cos(nx)+2\cos(kx)+2\cos(nx+kx)}+f(nx)+g(kx)$, for certain arbitrary $f$ and $g$ periodical  must have the same property (i.e., minimum of the integral at $k=n$) at the same time with  $\sqrt{3+2\cos(nx)+2\cos(kx)+2\cos(nx+kx)}$.

Comment: Last hint for you (I guess I shouldn't say "hint" because that would imply I know how to solve this!): $$|1+e^{inx}+e^{i(n+k)x}|=|2\cos((n+k)x/2)+e^{i(n-k)x/2}|.$$When $n=k$, this reduces to $|2\cos(nx)+1|$, and the integral is indeed $4\sqrt{3}+2\pi/3$ as already observed.

Comment: It seems that, unfortunately, the problem will remain unsolved. But you should not use the term "last" (never say never).